# How to add a file upload date and/or time in GridView using C# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string fileExtenstion = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
            if (fileExtenstion.ToLower() != ".doc" && fileExtenstion.ToLower() != ".docx")
            {
                Label1.Text = "Only files of docx extenstion are allowed";
                Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + FileUpload1.FileName));
                Label1.Text = "File Uploaded successfully";
                Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                string[] filepaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/"));
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DataRow dr;
                dt.Columns.Add("filenames");
                foreach (string filepath in filepaths)
                {
                    dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr["filenames"] = Path.GetFileName(filepath).ToString();
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Please upload the file";
            Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow gr = GridView1.SelectedRow;
        string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/upload/" + gr.Cells[0].Text);
        Response.ContentType = ContentType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filepath));
        Response.WriteFile(filepath);

        Response.End();
    }
```

So this code basically lets the user upload the file and display the name of the uploaded file that can be downloaded. No I created boundfield in Gridview. Can someone please tell me how to display file upload time and date to the same code shown above? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you storing the upload datetime anywhere?

Comment: At the moment, nah. But I do wanna know how to display it in a Gridview column. I mean, the date should be added as soon as the upload is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get both created and modification time of the file by using below methods.

DateTime creation = File.GetCreationTime(@"C:\test.txt");
DateTime modification = File.GetLastWriteTime(@"C:\test.txt");

Then you can add one more column in your data source for datetime to show it on GridView.

Thanks & Regards,
Dilshad Gulam Khan.

Comment: Where should I add this edit? I already created a boundfield column named Date.

Comment: Just add one column as you have added filenames column to your datatable for binding created time for each file. To bind each file created time use the File.GetCteationTime(pass your file path as you are passing to retrieve file name) method and bind with the respective column inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the UpLoadFile control, it is not possible to retrieve the file creation date by

uploading the file, so you can set the current time as the file upload time.

Code:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                string fileExtenstion = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
                if (fileExtenstion.ToLower() != ".doc" && fileExtenstion.ToLower() != ".docx")
                {
                    Label1.Text = "Only files of docx extenstion are allowed";
                    Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
                else
                {
                    string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + FileUpload1.FileName));
                    Label1.Text = "File Uploaded successfully";
                    Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    string[] filepaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/"));

                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    DataRow dr;
                    dt.Columns.Add("filenames");
                    dt.Columns.Add("date");
                    foreach (string filepath in filepaths)
                    {
                        dr = dt.NewRow();
                        dr["filenames"] = Path.GetFileName(filepath).ToString();
                        dr["date"] = date;
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "Please upload the file";
                Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank You. Really appreciate the help!!